# How to truncate an hex address?

Tags: javascript

So im writing an exploit and im getting an address such as 0x00708001e9ab0b10 which is obviously a 64 bit hex address. The address I need is 0x1e9ab0b10 to my calculations this is the upper 28 bits but some told me this is 48 bits and up so i dont know but i basically need to remove 0x0070800 the first 7 numbers of the hex string/number and give me something like 0x00000001e9ab0b10 which i would prefer!!! or something like 0x1e9ab0b10  mind you as well i need this done in JavaScript which is what my exploit is for

Comment: Is that a number? A string? Something else?

Comment: @Bergi yes its a hex string  the answer below is 0


Not sure I properly understand what you want, but if that hex is a string, you can call String.prototype.slice(x) on it which returns a copy of the string with the first x characters removed.

Comment: @Bergi  truncate = (hexString) => '0x0000000' + hexString.slice(9);

    truncate('0x00708001e9ab0b10');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I properly understand what you want, but if that hex is a string, you can call [String.prototype.slice(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on it which returns a copy of the string with the first `x` characters removed.

```js
    truncate = (hexString) => '0x0000000' + hexString.slice(9);

    truncate('0x00708001e9ab0b10');
```

Comment: I wish i could upvote this is exactly what i needed thank you alot this is the correct answer it yields me "0x00000001e9ab0b10"

Answer (score 0):

If the actual number isn't of any consequence then convert it into a string and slice it.

```js
console.log('0x'+0x00708001e9ab0b10.toString(16).slice(5))
```

Comment: this is also correct